# Default destination of JBoss ESB content based routing using Drools

Tags: jboss, esb, drools

I'm using content based routing with Drools in JBoss ESB. I have several rules that select the destinations to use base on message's content. If incoming message's content is not recognized, this message will be routed to the error handling service. Below is my Drools rules.

```
global java.util.List destinations;

rule "A"
when 
    Message (body.get("data") != null && body.get("data").class == A.class)
then
    destinations.add("a");  
end

rule "B"
when 
    Message (body.get("data") != null && body.get("data").class == B.class)
then
    destinations.add("b");  
end

rule "Unknown"
when
    eval(destinations.isEmpty())
then
    destinations.add("unknown");
end
```

The problem is that every message is routed to the error handling service, i.e. `unknown` is always added to the `destinations`. From my understanding, the rules are executed from top to bottom, then the last rule should not be executed if one of the above rules got executed.

How should I solve this issue? Some google searches show that I should use `salience`, is this the correct solution?

Comment: salience will be the simplest solution just give the default / "Unknown" rule a lower salience than the others. It will be a "correct" solution in the sense that salience is a feature provided by drools.

Answer (score 1):

I was also dumbstruck when faced with this problem. It's not just a matter of using a negative salience on the "Unknown" because the `eval()` in your example does not depend on a Drools fact and is thus executed first.

The following solution assumes that your destinations are mutually exclusive. That means you want your messages to be routed to `a`, `b` or `unknown`, but never to some combination of the three:

```
import org.jboss.soa.esb.message.Message;
import org.jboss.soa.esb.message.Body;

global java.util.List destinations;

rule "A"
 activation-group "destinations"
 when 
    Message (body.get("data") != null && body.get("data").class == A.class)
then
        destinations.add("a");  
end

rule "B"
 activation-group "destinations"
 when 
    Message (body.get("data") != null && body.get("data").class == B.class)
then
        destinations.add("b");  
end

rule "Unknown"
 activation-group "destinations"
 salience -9000
 when
    eval(destinations.isEmpty())
then
        destinations.add("unknown");
end
```

The `activation-group` declares this mutual-exclusive relation; such a group of rules will be fired depending on their order (salience) and facts, and if one rule in the group is fired the others will be ignored.

Inspiration was taken from an answer to [Drools - rule hierarchy and conditional execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10853994/983949) .